# Why does the statement “vector<int>(v1);” fail

Tags: c++, vector

A `vector<int>(v1)` expression yields a temporary object, and can be put on the right side of `operator=`, but if we use a `vector<int>(v1)` expression as a statement, it will fail in Visual Studio 2010 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel. Detailed error information is in comments in the following code.  Why does this happen?

```
vector<int> v1; 
v1.push_back( 10 );
v1.push_back( 20 );
v1.push_back( 30 );    
vector<int> v3 = vector<int>(v1);  //OK, deliberately code like this.
vector<int>(v1);  //error C2086: “std::vector<_Ty> v1”: redefinition
```

In the book *“C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices”*, chapter 82 *"Use the accepted idioms to really shrink capacity and really erase elements"*. There is a statement:

```
container<_Type>(c).swap(c);
```

I don’t understand and just want to test `container<_Type>(c)`, what does it mean?

Comment: Please use four spaces in front of code lines to mark them as code, and add newlines (for future posts, as @Yu Hao already edited your current post)

Comment: "if we use `vector(v1)` expression as a statement, [it fails]" -- ok but why would you want to do that?  What is it that you want to accomplish?

Comment: Why do you believe it is a valid statement? What effect do you expect it to have?

Comment: this is a result of ambiguity-resolution. if a construct can be parsed as a declaration, it is a declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that `vector<int>(v1)` is counterintuitive, but I do not see the point of using it. As others pointed out, this is standard behavior. If you're looking for a solution, here are 2 workarounds:

```
vector<int>::vector( v1 );
vector<int> { v1 };
```

**EDIT** (the question has changed): *"`container<_Type>(c).swap(c);` I don’t understand..."* This is different from `container<_Type>(c);`. A container may have a capacity larger than the one reported thru `size` (see `reserve`). The reserve helps minimize the number of some operations. If you add a new element, the container uses the already allocated memory. For instance, your vector might have room for 10 elements but it actually has only 1. If you add a new element, room for 8 elements is left. The above construct removes the reserve in order to conserve memory. First a copy of the original is made (this copy has no reserve). Then, the underlying data (pointer) of the original vector is replaced (see `swap`) by the new one, and the temporary object (which now owns the memory of the original) is discarded .

*"...to test `container<_Type>(c)`, what does it mean?"* Used as above it means *"create a temporary copy of c"*. Used in isolation, it looks like a copy constructor, but in fact it declares an object. The difference is given by the dot operator.

Answer (score 6):

`vector<int>(v1);` is same as `vector<int> v1;`. i.e. variable redefinition.

Comment: And the reason for these silly parentheses is that you need them for more complex cases like `std::vector<int> (*pFunc)(std::list<int>)`. The `*` goes with `pFunc`, not `std::vector<int>` here.

Answer (score 4):

> `vector<int>(v1)` expression yields a temporary object, and can be put on the right side of `operator=`, but if we use `vector<int>(v1)` expression as a statement, We will fail ...

The plain statement is handled differently by the compiler:

> ```
> vector<int>(v1); //error C2086: “std::vector<_Ty> v1”: redefinition
> ```

Is an alternative way of writing

```
vector<int> v1;
```

So you're redefining `v1` and the compiler complains.

---

To see your temporary initialization working use for instance

```
void foo(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
}
```

and call

```
foo(vector<int>(v1));
```

or simply<sup>1</sup>

```
(std::vector<int>)(v1); // this creates a temporary which is immediately disposed
```

[<kbd>See live demo for the latter</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63ddd5dc10befaa4)

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Stolen from [@Sergey A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5245033/sergeya)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36360508/1413395), but he preferred to delete it</sub>